# Recode multiple columns using dplyr

Tags: r, recode, dplyr

I had a dataframe where I recoded several columns so that 999 was set to NA

```
dfB <-dfA %>%
  mutate(adhere = if_else(adhere==999, as.numeric(NA), adhere)) %>%
  mutate(engage = if_else(engage==999, as.numeric(NA), engage)) %>%
  mutate(quality = if_else(quality==999, as.numeric(NA), quality)) %>%
  mutate(undrstnd = if_else(undrstnd==999, as.numeric(NA), undrstnd)) %>%
  mutate(sesspart = if_else(sesspart==999, as.numeric(NA), sesspart)) %>%
  mutate(attended = if_else(attended>=9, as.integer(NA), attended))
```

I want to use mutate_at() and a range of columns and recode() instead of if_else(), but I am stuck on how to give it the condition. I think something like  `999` = NA  based on some mutate_all examples -- but I also need the NA to match the type of .x and I am unsure how to get it to be type sensitive

I tried:

```
y <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,999,3,4), y2=c(1L, 2L, 999L, 3L, 4L), y3=c(T,T,F,F,T))
z <- y %>%
    mutate_at( vars(y1:y2), funs(recode(.,`999` = as.numeric(NA))))
```

But I get a warning "Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default " and I can see that it worded for the numeric column, but not for the integer column y2"

```
> z
  y1 y2    y3
1  1 NA  TRUE
2  2 NA  TRUE
3 NA NA FALSE
4  3 NA FALSE
5  4 NA  TRUE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, based on [dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):

> across() supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like summarise_at(), summarise_if(), and summarise_all().

So, using `mutate` and `across` instead is now recommended.

Like [Chris LeBoa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14083026/chris-leboa) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63347284/7002525), if you only want to convert an annoying value to `NA`, the function `na_if()` is probably the best choice:

```
y <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,999,3,4), y2=c(1L, 2L, 999L, 3L, 4L), y3=c(T,T,F,F,T))

y
   y1  y2    y3
1   1   1  TRUE
2   2   2  TRUE
3 999 999 FALSE
4   3   3 FALSE
5   4   4  TRUE
 
z <- y %>%
    mutate(across(
        y1:y2,
        ~na_if(., 999)
    ))

z
  y1 y2    y3
1  1  1  TRUE
2  2  2  TRUE
3 NA NA FALSE
4  3  3 FALSE
5  4  4  TRUE
```

Similarly, if you really want to `recode` values in multiple columns, you can follow the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203421/recode-using-dplyrmutate-across-not-working-in-a-function) from [bcarothers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892926/bcarothers):

```
df1 <- tibble(Q7_1=1:5,
              Q7_1_TEXT=c("let's","see","grogu","this","week"),
              Q8_1=6:10,
              Q8_1_TEXT=rep("grogu",5),
              Q8_2=11:15,
              Q8_2_TEXT=c("grogu","is","the","absolute","best"))

df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(
        starts_with("Q8") & ends_with("TEXT"),
        ~recode(., "grogu"="mando")
    ))
```

Answer (score 10):

I think it is related the column type. I added `mutate_if` to convert all integer columns to numeric, and then set the recode value to be `NA_real_`. It seems working.

```
library(dplyr)

y <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,999,3,4), y2=c(1L, 2L, 999L, 3L, 4L), y3=c(T,T,F,F,T))

z <- y %>%
  mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(y1:y2), funs(recode(.,`999` = NA_real_)))
z
#   y1 y2    y3
# 1  1  1  TRUE
# 2  2  2  TRUE
# 3 NA NA FALSE
# 4  3  3 FALSE
# 5  4  4  TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, www. this does solve the problem of the warning. it forces everything to real and avoids the wrong kind of NA for the previously integer columns. I had considered this. I have some other parts of the code that counts on those columns being integer and I will need to go reset them to integer after recoding. I was hoping for a way to make the NA value responsive to the kind of number in each column.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want to accomplish, so let me know if this isn't quite it.

```r
library(dplyr)

y <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,999,3,4), y2=c(1L, 2L, 999L, 3L, 4L), y3=c(T,T,F,F,T))

y

#>    y1  y2    y3
#> 1   1   1  TRUE
#> 2   2   2  TRUE
#> 3 999 999 FALSE
#> 4   3   3 FALSE
#> 5   4   4  TRUE

z <- y %>%
  mutate_at(vars(y1:y2), ~ifelse(. == 999, NA, .))

z

#>   y1 y2    y3
#> 1  1  1  TRUE
#> 2  2  2  TRUE
#> 3 NA NA FALSE
#> 4  3  3 FALSE
#> 5  4  4  TRUE
```

Comment: thanks evertr. This does solve the problem. It retains the if_else() instead of using recode() - but I can live with that. I can use the "." as you suggest to avoid changing to numeric. I am not clear why it does not complain that the NA for true is the wrong type. In my original code I had to use as.numeric(NA) or as.integer(NA) to avoid errors. DO you know why it does not give an error here?

Comment: ahh, OK. I see that you used ifelse() which does not check the type the same way that if_else() does. Do you know how this could be done with if_else() without casting the whole data frame as real?

Comment: @D.Bontempo you could use `mutate_if(is.numeric, ...)`, which also matches integers, such that you don't have to select all the variables (like in the solution from @www, but without converting anything). @everetr I'd recommend to remove that `as.numeric` from your solution, because there is no need for type-convertion. Then it would be +1-worthy ;-)

Comment: @Tino, See my comment below the code. I already said one can omit `as.numeric`, if desired. I didn't know if @D. Bontempo wanted conversion or not.

Comment: @D.Bontempo See my comment below the code. You can omit `as.numeric` to avoid converting `y$y2` from `integer` to `numeric`.

Comment: @everetr but there is no need for converting to numeric at all, or do I miss something? Therefore, I'd omit `as.numeric` at all...

Comment: @Tino Omitted. Ellipsis averted.

Comment: @everetr - thanks I will not change to numeric. The key bit here really was that ifelse() does not police types and if_else does(). I solved the problem by adopting ifelse. I think if I had to use if_else, I would write a function to return me a NA value that matched.

Answer (score 7):

Now that `funs` has been depreciated in dplyr, here's the new way to go:

```
z <- y %>%
  mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(y1:y2), list(~recode(.,`999` = NA_real_)))
```

Replace `funs` with `list` and insert a `~` before `recode`.

Comment: `list()` isn't necessary if only one function is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to recode something to an NA the na_if() function should also work.