# recode multiple columns `mutate_at` with unused arguments error

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'm trying to recode values in multiple columns, which with the same coding scheme. I use code `mutate_at` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521920/recode-multiple-columns-using-dplyr) but did not work.

My data frame is like this, and I want to recode "Neutral = 3" and "Agree = 4"

```
A              B            C
Neutral       Agree        Neutral
Neutral       Agree        Agree
Agree         Neutral      Neutral
```

My code

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(c("A", "B", "C"), funs(as.character)) %>%
  mutate_at(c("A", "B", "C"), funs(recode(.,"Neutral"=3, "Agree"=4)))
```

Error shows

```
Error in recode(A, Neutral = 3, Agree = 4) : 
  unused arguments (Neutral = 3, Agree = 4)
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW: Except for a warning ... your code works fine on my machine using dplyr 0.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(~recode(., "Neutral"=3, "Agree"=4))
#If there are other columns
#df %>%  mutate_at(vars(A:C), ~recode(., "Neutral"=3, "Agree"=4))

#  A B C
#1 3 4 3
#2 3 4 4
#3 4 3 3
```

We can also use `ifelse`/`case_when` if there are limited values that can be taken.

```
df %>%  mutate_all(~ifelse(.  == "Neutral", 3, 4))
```

Or in base R using `lapply`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == "Neutral", 3, 4))
```